# svnsync fails to get lock after deleting revprop

Tags: svn, svnsync

I've tried to remove the svnsync lock property as described in the thread titled "svnsync - couldn't get lock on destination repos", but it didn't work.  When I try to run svnsync, it still gives me the Failed to get lock error.  I've removed the svn:svn-lock revprop on both the source and mirror repository.

Can anyone help me figure this out? (Any help at all would be highly appreciated)

Thanks!